# Google Play expansion file: downloaded file is damaged

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, apk-expansion-files

I need an expansion file for my app that contains media files. 
I uploaded my signed apk to the play store, added the expansion file and started an alpha test.
When I downloaded the app, the expansion file was downloaded also. It is in the `Android/obb/com.name.appname` folder. But the name of the file is `temp.main.1000004.com.name.appname.obb`. The size is 423 MB, but I can't copy it to my mac. The file seems to be damaged.

I created the expansion file with the command
`zip -v -dc -r -x \*.DS_Store -Z store main_expansion main_expansion` like described [here](https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/adding-an-android-apk-expansion-file-to-a-cordova-project/) in the section 'Make Zip Archive Expansion File'.

The app is a hybrid app created with Cordova and Ionic. 
I use Cordova 6 and I added the plugin "cordova-plugin-xapkreader.git#cordova-6.3" to my app. This plugin should make the .obb file readable. But I don't think this is the problem.

Does anybody have an idea why the file is damaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my expansion file isn't damaged. I looked at the phone storage with android file transfer. There, the file is named `temp.main.1000004.com.name.appname.obb`. But when I look directly in the folder with a folder browser on my phone, the app has the correct name `main.1000004.com.name.appname.obb`. So it's a bug of android file transfer.